# Creating a simple simulation of the "universe" with constructor

Tags: javascript, object, methods, constructor

Here is my homework assignment. It's about building a "universe model" so there is no easy way to put this assignment into one sentence. However it's a beginners exercise that requires constructors, methods and objects.

1. **Goal:** I should create a representation of the universe where matter and energy is conserved.
2. **Basic Setup:** I should work with an object called Universe that contains two objects within: matter and energy. (Please note beginner level)
3. **Scenarios to accomplish / how the "universe" should function:**

   - Matter is destroyed: amount of energy in the universe needs to be increased by the amount of matter destroyed
   - Matter is created:  amount of energy in the universe needs to be decreased by the amount of matter created
   - Energy is destroyed: amount of matter in the universe needs to be increased by the amount of energy destroyed
   - Energy is created: amount of matter in the universe needs to be decreased by the amount of energy created

**4. Respect this when building the object:**

Basically matter and energy influence each other in a negative relation.
- Implement this objects using context
- The matter and energy objects are defined within an object called Universe
- No other variable should be defined out of the Universe object
- It should be possible to give an initial amount to either the energy or the matter, otherwise should default to 0.

**5. Examples of how it is supposed to work:**

> ```
> var universe = new Universe(10, 'matter')
> Universe.matter.total // 10 
> Universe.energy.total // 0
>
> // or with no initial amount 
> var universe = new Universe()
> Universe.matter.total // 0 
> Universe.energy.total // 0 
> Universe.matter.destroy(5) // 0 
> Universe.eatter.total // -5 
> Universe.energy.total // 5 
> Universe.energy.destroy(-5) // 0 
> Universe.matter.total // -10 
> Universe.energy.total // 10 
> Universe.energy.create(5) // 0 
> Universe.matter.total // -15 
> Universe.energy.total // 15
> ```

This is my code and I run into a syntax error ("{ not expected")

```
class Universe {

    constructor (amount, matter = 0, energy = 0) {
        this.amount = amount;
        this.matter = matter;
        this.energy = energy
    }

    matter(amount) {
        destroy(amount) {
            this.matter = this.matter - amount;
            this.energy = this.energy + amount;
            return this.amount
        }

        create(amount) {
            this.matter = this.matter + amount;
            this.energy = this.energy - amount;
            return this.amount

        }

        total(amount) {
            return this.amount
        }
    }

    energy (amount) {
        destroy(amount) {
            this.energy = this.energy - amount;
            this.matter = this.matter + amount;
            return this.amount


        }

        create(amount) {
            this.energy = this.energy + amount;
            this.matter = this.matter - amount;
            return this.amount

        }

        total(amount) {
            return this.amount
        }
    }
}
```

**The questions is where to correct the code so that it runs? Please try to stick to my level of knowledge (and sample code as much as possible).**

Comment: You can't define member functions inside of others like that.

Comment: What is `matter(amount)  ... {destroy(amount) {` supposed to even mean?

Comment: @ThisIsNoZaku How else can I define it in order to able to call the function like this: 

`Universe.matter.destroy(5) `

Comment: First define a class of `matter` objects? A universe object could then have some of those objects as members.

Comment: @JohnColeman you mean, I set Universe as normal object instead of class and instead create a class for both matter and energy?

Comment: @JohnColeman that probably means nothing and I am messing up the syntax big time

Comment: There are different ways of doing things. Objects can clearly have other objects as members. You can either predefine the member objects in their own class definitions, or figure out the correct way of defining them all at once. I don't have time to write an answer right now, but hopefully someone will soon.

Comment: @JohnColeman thx for your hints. Hope so too because I feel stuck. Not even sure if it is best practice to post such lengthy posts here.

Answer (score 1):

The Universe class is fine, but if you want objects with type Matter, you need to create a Matter class as well. You can't define properties on a class that are classes themselves with the kind of syntax you're using; you need to create a separate class and define the property equal to a new instance of that class.

So once you have a Matter class, you can then set `this.matter = new Matter()` in the Universe class so that you can reference `universe.matter` (assuming `universe` is an instance of the Universe class, created with something like `const universe = new Universe()`)